# Trying to Center Table Cell button - HTML EMAIL

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

Please see Pastebin, I'm trying to center the "BUILD FOR FREE NOW" button, but for some reason `align="center"` is not working. What Am I doing wrong?

My Code Was Long ..
So I put it here : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kxWdbe5S)

Here's the portion of the code (my button) that I need centered:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" width="240" bgcolor="#cf142b" style="background: #cf142b; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; display: block;"><a href="" style="display:block;color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">BUILD FOR FREE NOW</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move those style attributes from your  to your  tag.

```html
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #f5f5f5; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding:40px 0 0 0;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;"> <a href="#"><img src="img/logo-header.png" alt="Welcome" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size:16px;color:#666666;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <b>Hello, Mike!</b>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="color:#444444;padding: 20px 0 20px 0;"> <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit!</b>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><a href="" style="width:240px; background: #cf142b; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding:15px 10px 15px 10px;">BUILD FOR FREE NOW</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Call to Action</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#0B5EA8">
                        <td>Footer</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cCeNd/

Let me know if its the one you looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Need to dust off my HTML tables book from 1998 :p

Comment: You're welcome. Just another suggestion, you might want to put those css code into a <style> tag or external stylesheet. Would make it look less confusing and organized. Cheers!

Comment: The HTML is for email - should all be inline CSS styling

Comment: oh right. I totally missed that :p

Comment: Think I'd be designing a website with tables and inline styling...c'mon. :p

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I was centering the wrong element.

Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;`? That might not be cross-client, but your rounded corners won't be either.

Another option would be to make a 3 celled table to fake centering the button.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the exact code I want centered. Please see my edit to my post.

Comment: Also, can't use `margin` in email HTML. Rounded corners I know there will be limited functionality.

Comment: Margin is supported better than rounded corners - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/